# Cisco Catalyst 3560 password recovery, config.text to running-config returns garbage

Tags: cisco, switch

Greetings.

I'm the new IT guy after the last IT guy just up and left. He took all knowledge of the network including router and switch passwords. I've been running the password recovery procedure on all of our switches and have been successful on all but one (a Catalyst 3560).

I've gone through the steps of [Cisco Document ID: 12040](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps628/products_password_recovery09186a0080094184.shtml) up to step 12. At step 12 I copy flash:config.text to system:running-config, press Enter, the screen blanks and I get a short line of garbage characters. I mash Enter a few times, the line changes, but it's still garbage.

I rebooted the switch and it seems to be working but I can't log on.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because the guy change the console setting in the configuration file, so once you load it new settings are applied and it mismatch with your current settings (9600 baud, 8 bit, ...).
Hopefully there is a better way than guessing value he sets.
Between step 11 and 12 run `more flash:config.text`, this will display the configuration that will be applied. Check for rxspeed/txspeed/databit/.. in the `line con 0` part. Do step 12 then change you terminal settings with right one. Then it enter few time and it should work.

Comment: Yes! That is what it was! When I saw garbage (or even when I plugged in and didn't get a prompt at all) I changed my PuTTY settings to 115200 and the prompt appeared!

I was quite psyched.

Thank you!